# Postgresql index not used in inner join

Tags: postgresql, inner-join, postgresql-performance

I am using 9.1

Here is the query:

```
select a.id,b.flag              
from a, b               
where b.starting_date>='2002-01-01'::date               
and a.zip_code= b.zip_code              
and abs( a.date1-b.date1 ) <=60                 
and abs( a.balance-b.balance ) <=1000               
and abs( a.value-b.value ) <=3000
```

Where table a and b have every single field indexed (not multi-column index) using btree.

Here is `explain analyze verbose` results:

```
Merge Join  (cost=0.00..448431434.24 rows=440104742 width=16) (actual time=384.268..15151912.652 rows=672144 loops=1)   
  Output: a.id, b.flag  
  Merge Cond: (a.zip_code = b.zip_code) 
  Join Filter: ((abs((a.date1 - b.date1)) <= 60) AND (abs((a.balance - b.balance)) <= 1000) AND (abs((a.value - b.value)) <= 3000)) 
  ->  Index Scan using indx_a_zip_code on a  (cost=0.00..950851.26 rows=6800857 width=32) (actual time=0.028..22292.274 rows=2080440 loops=1)   
        Output: a.id, a.zip_code, a.date1, a.balance, a.value   
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1906889.40 rows=19744024 width=28) (actual time=0.032..6148075.701 rows=6472114362 loops=1)  
        Output: b.balance, b.date1, b.zip_code, b.starting_date, b.value,   
        ->  Index Scan using indx_zip_code on  b  (cost=0.00..1857529.34 rows=19744024 width=28) (actual time=0.025..76893.104 rows=19078422 loops=1)   
              Output:b.balance, b.date1, b.zip_code, b.starting_date    
              Filter: (b.starting_date >= '2002-01-01'::date)   
Total runtime: 15155983.643 ms
```

It appears to me that the query planner is using index for zip_code but not other fields. I have 8 million rows in table a and 20 million rows in table b and it takes 3 hours to finish (The RAM is 64GB, and all critical postgresql server configurations have been tuned according to:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Any advice/suggestion is appreciated. Thanks a million!

Comment: Please add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` instead of the "plain" `analyze`. A multi-column index on `b (zip_code, starting_date)` might be beneficial. You should also get used to using an explicit `JOIN` operator rather than the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the `where` clause.

Comment: Please also give details on your index definitions and/or the schema.

Comment: the definition of index is standard (I using pgadmin III): create index index_name on a (single_field_name);

Comment: I am running explain analyze and will post it once it is done. Thanks

Comment: The query *expects* 440104742 tuples from the product a JOIN b ON zipcode. I am curious what the number of *rows removed by filter* will be...

Comment: Postgres **is** using an index for the join on both tables. Which index do you expect it to use in addition if you only have single column indexes? The additional `where` conditions that use columns from both tables can't use any index, so the only indexes left are the ones on `zip_code` and  potentially one on `starting_date` - but that will only be used if it reduces the number of rows _substantially.

Comment: PostgreSQL query planner will consider using a B-tree index whenever an indexed column is involved in a comparison using one of these operators:

<
<=
=
>=
>Constructs equivalent to combinations of these operators, such as BETWEEN and IN, can also be implemented with a B-tree index search. Also, an IS NULL or IS NOT NULL condition on an index column can be used with a B-tree index.

Comment: according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/indexes-types.html

Comment: I am expect query planner to use indices on zip_code, date1, balance, value.

Comment: Any DBMS unable to use indexes on fields when them used inside expressions like in your query. It is possible to create [Indexes on Expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-expressional.html) but I am not sure that it possible for expressions on several tables. PS: do not mix joining and filtering conditions, use `... join ... on <join conditions> where <filter conditions>` instead.

Comment: Thanks Abelisto. I got rid of abs function and replace it with <= and >= constraints and ended up with the similar explain results

Comment: the explain analyze verbose result was updated in the post, thank you